# Assign ID to html text

Tags: javascript, html

How do I go about assigning certain words a unique id tag using vanilla javascript?  For example:

```html
<p>All the king's horses ran away.</p>
```

The word "All" gets the id "term1", "King's" gets "term2", "away" gets "term3", etc. but **not** every word in the sentence will get assigned an id.

I am currently using the replace method but I think it's the wrong approach:

```js
var str = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;

function addId() {
  txt = str.replace(/all/i, '<span id="term1">$&</span>').replace(/king's/i, '<span id="term2">$&</span>').replace(/away/i, '<span id="term3">$&</span>');
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = txt;
}

window.onload = function() {
  addId();
};
```

```html
<p>All the king's horses ran away.</p>
```

This forces me to chain a bunch of replace commands, changing the id name each time. I don't think this is the best solution.  What is best way to do this?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you define which words will get an ID?

Comment: Your regular expression only matches "`all`" and your code wraps it in `span#term1` - where are the other words defined and `term2`, `term3`? It doesn't look like you're posting all of your code.

Comment: I added code for `term2` and `term3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should make the job done. You can replace blacklist with whitelist. That will depend on your use case. Also, `addIds` can use `Array.map` instead of `Array.forEach` that will make the whole function a one-liner. This example is imperative because it will be more readable.

```js
// string - string where we want to add ids
// blackList - words we want to skip (can be whiteliste black list is more general)
function addIds(string, blackList = ['the', 'a']) {
  const stringArray = string.split(' ') // split string into separate words
  let stringWithIds = string // this will be final string

  stringArray.forEach((item, index) => {
    // skip word if black listed
    if (blackList.indexOf(item.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      return
    }
    stringWithIds = stringWithIds.replace(item, `<span id="term${index}">${item}</span>`) // add id to word if not black listed
  })

  // replace string with our string with ids
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = stringWithIds;
}

window.onload = function() {
  const str = document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
  addIds(str); // you can pass custom blacklist as optional second parameter
};
```

```html
<p>All the king's horses ran away.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this function would be flexible enough for the task:

```js
// Here, your logic to decide if the word must be tagged
const shouldBeTagged = word => {
  return true
}

function addId(str) {
  // Split the string into individual words to deal with each of them
  // one by one
  let txt = str.split(' ').map((word, i) => {
  // Should this word be tagged
   if (shouldBeTagged(word)) {
      // If so, tag it
     return '<span id="term' + i + '">' + word + '</span>'
   } else {
      // Otherwise, return the naked word
     return word
   }
  // Join the words together again
  }).join(' ')
  document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = txt;
}

window.onload = function() {
  addId(document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML);
};
```

```html
<p>All the king's horses ran away.</p>
```